# JSON.NET Serialize Date

Tags: c#, json.net

I would like to serialize my date to be in a specific format but I can't get my act together.

I tried building a nice little class but the output gets wrapped in quotes, which doesn't work.

I'd like the JSON to look like this...

```
{ 
    date : new Date(2013, 8, 30) 
}
```

but I get this...

```
{
    date: "new Date(2013, 8, 30)" 
}
```

my class

```
public class DateCell : ChartCell
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public DateTime Value { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "date")]
    public override object DataValue
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("new Date({0}, {1}, {2})", this.Value.Year, this.Value.Month - 1, this.Value.Day);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a difference between a JavaScript Object and JSON.  What you described might be valid in a JavaScript object, but it is not valid JSON.  JSON does not allow the representation that you are asking for.

In JSON a value can only be one of the following:

- A string, such as `"abc"`
- A number, such as `123` or `-12.34`
- A literal value of `true`, `false`, or `null`
- An array of other valid values, such as `[1,"a",true]`
- Another JSON object, such as `{ a: 1, b: "abc" }`

It cannot just be a *JavaScript Object*, or any other arbitrary JavaScript.  See the spec at [json.org](http://www.json.org/).

Passing a `Date` object constructor would not make any sense, as JSON is a general purposed serialization format, and `Date` is a JavaScript native class.  How would you expect non-JavaScript code to interpret this?

While there is no specific date or time format defined by the JSON standard, the *de facto* standard is the ISO 8601 format.  Your `DateTime` would look something like `"2013-09-30T00:00:00"`.  There are other ways to serialize a date, but they are not as uniform or popular.

In JSON.Net, the ISO 8601 format is the default.  So you don't need to do anything special other than just to serialize your object with its original properties.

```
public class DateCell : ChartCell
{
    public DateTime Value { get; set; }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Since you said in comments that you are passing this to Google Charts, it appears [from their reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_toJSON) that they are using a nonstandard format that *looks* like the `Date` constructor, but has omitted the `new` keyword.  Why they do this, I'm not sure, but you should be able to modify your original code as follows:

```
public class DateCell : ChartCell
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public DateTime Value { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "date")]
    public override object DataValue
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("Date({0},{1},{2})", this.Value.Year, this.Value.Month - 1, this.Value.Day);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow that's a lot of info. Thanks, typically I want valid JSON, but I am passing the value to another javascript library that wants that particular format, I am trying to find a clean way to pass that value. But it might just be a bad idea.

Comment: If it shows that format, it is talking about a JavaScript Object - not a string of JSON encoded text.  What library?

Comment: I am trying to use google charts. If I create the objects in javascript no problem. but I am getting data from the server so I want to pass JSON. Side note, I know the name of the property in the data table api is "v" not "date".

Comment: Should I pull the data back and then roll through it to create new js objects?

Comment: Have you *tried* just passing the JSON into the library the way that it comes out by default?  It should probably work.